# linux - for loop with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

My file have below data

```
IP      USER    PASSWORD
ip1     user1   password1
ip2     user2   password2
ip3     user3   password3
```

So I write below script for same

```
#!/bin/bash

for val in  `awk 'NR>1 {print}' servers.list`
do
        echo  $val
done
```

But for loop is been execute 9 times and if I wrote `awk` command in quotes then its execute only single time.

How can I write a script so that for loop treats every line as single so that I could parse each line and can use `pscp`to copy data into multiple server.

**Command**

```
pscp -p mypassword /home/user/myfile.txt user@ip:/home/user/myfile.txt
```

---

If is there any better way then this to copy file into multiple server then pls
specify it bcz I am new in scripting.

Comment: Why do you need to run shell loop with awk. awk can generate same output easily without any loop.

Comment: @anubhava I am learning the scripting, so if you can share you knowledge or any blog (if already 
been describe over there) then it will be grateful for me. BTW I need to execute `pscp` command too thats why I am doing this way.

Comment: Can you share an example of `pscp` command?

Comment: @anubhava `pscp -p mypassword /home/user/myfile.txt user@ip:/home/user/myfile.txt`

Comment: As a start copy/paste your code into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues that it tells you about.

Comment: `for` loop iterates nine times because there are nine items in the `for` list: `ip1`, `user1`, `password1`, `ip2`, `user2`, `password2`, `ip3`, `user3`, `password3`

Comment: @EdMorton is there any better way to copy file to multiple server with scripting?

Comment: Please just ask one question at a time. You already have 2 separate questions in your "question" above. If/when you get an answer to this question you asked, accept it and then you can ask a new, separate followup question if you have one.

Comment: Do not extend your question if someone has already answered. Thank you.

Comment: @EdMorton I am tring to break the question, let me edit the question into 1.

Comment: @Cyrus Agreed with you but answers leading to somewhere I cant extend my use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you actually need is:

```
while read -r ip user password; do
    pscp -p "$password" "/home/${user}/myfile.txt" "${user}@${ip}:/home/${user}/myfile.txt"
done < <(tail -n +2 servers.list)
```

which really has nothing to do with what you asked for at the top of your question.

The above assumes no white space within fields nor other undesirable characters in your `servers.list` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 {printf "IP --> %s, user --> %s, password --> %s\n",$1,$2,$3}' servers.list
IP --> ip1, user --> user1, password --> password1
IP --> ip2, user --> user2, password --> password2
IP --> ip3, user --> user3, password --> password3
```

When you want formatted output, like in your example, `printf` is very useful.  The command format is `printf fmt, expr-list` where `fmt` is a string with placeholders, like `%s`, that are filled in from the values in the expression list.